# Remove duplicates in each line of a file

Tags: linux, bash, perl, uniq

How can I remove duplicates in each line, for example here?

```
1 1 1 2 1 2 3
5 5 4 1 2 3 3
```

I'd like to get this output:

```
1 2 3 
5 4 1 2 3
```

There are lots of lines (100,000) and in each line I want unique values.
Perl might be the fastest, but how can I do it in Perl or Bash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an option using awk:

```
awk '{ while(++i<=NF) printf (!a[$i]++) ? $i FS : ""; i=split("",a); print ""}' infile > outfile
```

**Edit** Updated with comments:

1. `while (++i<=NF)`

   Initializes the while loop, precrementing "i" since $0 is the full line in awk.

   So it starts at $1 (first field).  Loops through the line until the end (less than or equal to  'NF' which is built into awk for "Number of Fields").  The default field separator is a  space, you could change the default separator easily.
2. `printf (!a[$i]++) ? $i FS : ""`

   This is a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

   So, if input is not in the array `!a[$i]++`, then it prints $i, if it is, it prints "".  (You could remove the `!` and reverse the `$i FS : ""` if you don't like it this way).
3. `i=split("",a)`

   Normally, that's a null split.  In this case, it resets I for the next line.
4. `print ""`

   ends the line for the output (not 100% why, actually), otherwise you would have an output of:

   `1 2 3 5 4 1 2 3` instead of 
   `1 2 3`
   `5 4 1 2 3`

Comment: To help current and future readers, please try to document answers to some extent. This is compact and efficient, but it is quite unreadable for someone not very used to `awk` since it relies on test and operation order, the ternary operator, the `split("",a)` quirk to reset an array (and its return value for resetting `i`) and special variables `NF` and `FS`. Such an explanation makes an answer even better!

Comment: @DanielAndersson My apology for being lazy, updated.  Thanks!

Comment: nerdwaller: the reason you get 1 2 3 5 4 1 2 3 w/o step 4 is that all your output is done via printf, w/ no \n ever thrown in ...

Comment: Step 2 works since it increments the array value with the index of the current number. If this index was empty, the test returns `!false`, and the increment is done _after_ the comparison. The next time the loop finds the same number, the comparison will return `!true` since the value corresponding to the index was set to a value the last time. The field is incremented again, but this "total count" is not used later (it doesn't hurt, though).

Comment: In step 3, the array `a` is deleted for the next line iteration. `split("",a)` is a shorthand to delete an array `a` (see [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Delete.html#fn-1) for a notice). As a side effect, this operation also returns `0`, and since `i` should be set to `0` for the next iteration, the `split()` call is used instead for assignment instead of a separate `i=0` call, saving some characters (at expense of readability, perhaps).

Answer (score 5):

Since `ruby` comes with any Linux distribution I know of:

```
ruby -e 'STDIN.readlines.each { |l| l.split(" ").uniq.each { |e| print "#{e} " }; print "\n" }' < test
```

Here, `test` is the file that contains the elements.

To explain what this command does—although Ruby can almost be read from left to right:

- Read the input (which comes from `< test` through your shell)
- Go through each line of the input
- Split the line based on one space separating the items, into an array (`split(" ")`)
- Get the unique elements from this array (in-order)
- For each unique element, print it, including a space (`print "#{e} "`)
- Print a newline once we're done with the unique elements

Answer (score 2):

Not pure bash, but ...:

```
while read line; do
    printf "%s\n" $line | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '
    echo ''
done < file
```

The lines will be sorted as a byproduct.